# const { __ } not working in IE11

Tags: javascript

The setting of constants:

```
const {__, _x, _n, sprintf} = wp.i18n;
```

does not work in Ie11 and Safari browsers. It returns an error in the console:

```
Expected identifier
```

marking the "{" character.

Is there a way to define them that does work?

Comment: IE does not support const, and the `{} =` syntax requires Safari 8. To use these in older browsers you need to compile the code with Babel, or similar, tri create backward compatible code.

Comment: `"use strict";

var _wp$i18n = wp.i18n,
    __ = _wp$i18n.__,
    _x = _wp$i18n._x,
    _n = _wp$i18n._n,
    sprintf = _wp$i18n.sprintf;` if anyone else needs it. Thank you for the tip @JacobPeattie